# Hibernate error with #new

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.1

I get this error with Hibernate 5.1 with JPA 2.1 on WildFly 12:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not locate setter method for property [rs.co.bora5.programs.sevid.model.Klijent#new]

And i have implemented all getters setters, no-args constructor...

Answer (score 0):

In the end, it was problem with mapped superclass... 
I added method

```
public Boolean isNew() {
return id == null;
}
```

that was supposed to tell me if object was persisted and somehow Hibernate asked for setter for field new because of that. After i deleted method `isNew()` everything was ok.